# Is there the ability to use CSS variables in React Native or is there an alternative?

Tags: css, react-native

When working in web, I use CSS variables for various components to be more reusable when in different containers. In the code below, you'll see that **heading**, **paragraph**, **image**, and **dropdown** are reused in two different containers (**modal-small** and **modal-large**).

Each of the components controls it's own spacing but it uses CSS variables that are set in the container so that it adapts to the requirements of the container (See CSS below).

I would really like to do something similar (preferably exactly the same) in React Native, however, I'm unsure how best to go about it.

(Note, I found the post linked below in my search, but it's the only thing I can find that says CSS variables are possible in React Native and the explanation of how to do it is confusing and I don't quite understand how it's being applied since AFAIK everything needs to be through the stylesheet API)
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-css-variables-react-native/ )

My example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.modal-small {
  --p-top: 15px;
  --p-side: 15px;
  
  /* Below stuff is not relevant to demo */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 330px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-large {
  --p-top: 15px;
  --p-side: 30px;
  
  /* Below stuff is not relevant to demo */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}



.heading {
  margin: calc(2*var(--p-top)) var(--p-side) 0;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.paragraph {
  margin: var(--p-top) var(--p-side) 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.image {
  margin: var(--p-top) var(--p-side) 0;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: var(--p-top) var(--p-side) 0;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-small">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
</div>

<div class="modal-large">
  <div class="heading"></div>
  <div class="paragraph"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="dropdown"></div>
  <div class="heading"></div>
</div>
```